# How to use the value of a string in an enum as an input to output the rest of the data for that enum item in Java?

Tags: java, loops, validation, input, enums

I couldn't really think of how to phrase the question, but I have a fairly simple program that will ask the user to input an element from the periodic table and then will output the symbol, group and atomic mass of that element. Currently it will only accept an input of the name of the element, and I'm trying to make it accept an input of the symbol too, but I don't know how to do that. For example, at the moment if the user inputs "Iron", the program will output correctly, but if they input "Fe" it will not work. I want the input of "Fe" to work as well. I'm very new to Java, so a simple explanation as to how and why would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PeriodicTable {

    public enum Element {
        Hydrogen("H", "Nonmetal", "1.008"),
        Helium("He", "Noble Gas", "4.003"),
        Lithium("Li", "Alkali Metal", "6.941"),
        Beryllium("Be", "Alkaline Earth", "9.012"),
        Boron("B", "Semimetal", "10.811"),
        Carbon("C", "Nonmetal", "12.011"),
        //The rest of the periodic table is here, I just removed it for the sake of this post.

        private String symbol;
        private String group;
        private String weight;

        private Element(String symbol, String group, String weight) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.group = group;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }

    static Element cName = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of an element in the periodic table. ");
        do {
            String input = reader.nextLine();
            try {
                cName = Element.valueOf(input.trim().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.trim().substring(1).toLowerCase());
            } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("That name is not valid. Please try again. ");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Element: " + cName + " (" + cName.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + cName.group + "\nAtomic Mass: " + cName.weight);
            reader.close();
            break;
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a method to your enum that iterates all values and return the one that matches the `symbol`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection `Element.values()` contains all the values of your enum class.  
After the user gives input, loop through this collection and check the `symbol` property to find the element.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean found = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the symbol of an element in the periodic table. ");
        String input = reader.nextLine().trim();

        for (Element e : Element.values()) {
            if (e.symbol.equals(input)) {
                found = true;
                System.out.println("Element: " + e + " (" + e.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + e.group + "\nAtomic Mass: " + e.weight);
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            System.out.println("That symbol is not valid. Please try again. ");
    } while (!found);
    reader.close();
}
```